# Get exclusive users in each table

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables as shown below

[image]

For each table I want the count of users that are present exclusively in that table (not present in other tables). The result should look something likes this

[image]

I have one way of getting desired result as shown below:

First Column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) table1_only
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table2
           
           UNION 
           
           SELECT DISTINCT id 
           FROM table3
           
           UNION
           
           SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table4) B
           
 ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

Second Column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) table2_only
FROM table2 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table1
           
           UNION 
           
           SELECT DISTINCT id 
           FROM table3
           
           UNION
           
           SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table4) B
           
 ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

Third Column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) table3_only
FROM table3 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table1
           
           UNION 
           
           SELECT DISTINCT id 
           FROM table2
           
           UNION
           
           SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table4) B
           
 ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

Fourth Column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) table4_only
FROM table4 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table1
           
           UNION 
           
           SELECT DISTINCT id 
           FROM table2
           
           UNION
           
           SELECT DISTINCT id
           FROM table3) B
           
 ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

But I wanted to know if there is any efficient and scalable way to get same result. Just for 4 tables the amount of code is too much.

Any ways of optimizing this task will be really helpful.

[Sample fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k4oX3dQp3L24enRNTGp5Xe/0). (This fiddle is for mysql, I am looking for a generic SQL based approach than any db specific approach)

**P.S.:**
There is no complusion on the result needs to be in column wise. It can be row wise as well, as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this by combining the data from all tables.  Then aggregate and filter:

```
select which, count(*) as num_in_table_only
from (select id, min(which) as which, count(*) as cnt
      from ((select id, 1 as which from table1) union all
            (select id, 2 as which from table2) union all
            (select id, 3 as which from table3) union all
            (select id, 4 as which from table4)
           ) t
      group by id
     ) i
where cnt = 1
group by which
```

Note:  In your sample data, the `id`s are unique in each table.  This solution assumes that is true, but can easily be tweaked to handle duplicates within a table.

Comment: Starting to wonder if you are actually an AI Gordon :)

Comment: Highly scalable solution for multiple tables. I believe changing `union all` to `union` in the subquery will take care of duplicates.

Comment: @sql_learner . . . Yes, but that also degrades performance -- unless you have an index on `id` in each of the tables.

Comment: @Charleh . . . If anyone wants to replace me with AI, I would be happy to help.